# IntegrationError: Invalid value for confirmCardPayment: payment_method.card should be an object or element. You specified: null

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a payment gateway. But when I try to pay after filling the details, getting the error

> IntegrationError: Invalid value for confirmCardPayment: payment_method.card should be an object or element. You specified: null.

Is using Elements component inside index.js might be a reason?

Here is Payment.js`

```
const Payment = () => {
    const stripePubKey = 'My_key';
const stripeApiKey = loadStripe(stripePubKey);
    const paymentData = {
        amount:Math.round(orderInfo.totalPrice * 100)   
    }
    const  submitHandler=async(e)=>{
e.preventDefault()
try {
 const config = {
    headers:{
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
 }  
 const {data} = await axios.post(
    "/api/v1/payment/process",
    paymentData,
    config
  );
 const client_secret = data.client_secret
 if(!stripe||!elements) return;
 const result = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(client_secret, {
    payment_method: {
      card: elements.getElement(CardNumberElement),
      billing_details: {
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email,
        address: {
          user.address
        },
      },
    },
 });
if(result.error){
    payBtn.current.disabled = false
    alert.error(result.error.message)
}
else{
    if(result.paymentIntent.status ==="succeeded"){
navigate('/success')
    }
    else{
        alert.error("Error")
    }
}
} catch (error) {
    payBtn.current.disabled = false
   console.log(error)
}
    }
  return (
 <Fragment>
<Elements stripe={stripeApiKey}>
    <form className='paymentForm' onSubmit={(e)=>submitHandler(e)}>
        <div>
            <CreditCardIcon/>      
            <CardNumberElement className='paymentInput'/>
         </div>
        <div>
            <EventIcon/>        
            <CardExpiryElement className='paymentInput'/>        
        </div>
        <div>
            <VpnKeyIcon/>         
            <CardCvcElement className='paymentInput'/>             
        </div>
    </form>
    </Elements>
</div>
 </Fragment>
  )
}
```

Here is my index.js

```
const stripePubKey = 'my_key';
const stripePromise = loadStripe(stripePubKey);
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
    <App />
      </Elements> 
);
```

Comment: It's likely that you have two `<Elements>` that CardNumberElement isn't picked up correctly. Can you ensure only one <Elements> is used?